# Why is using named routes for generating outbound URLs a violation of Separation of Concerns?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, design-patterns, separation-of-concerns

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns

> In computer science, separation of concerns (SoC) is the process of
>   breaking a computer program into distinct features that overlap in
>   functionality as little as possible. A concern is any piece of
>   interest or focus in a program. Typically, concerns are synonymous
>   with features or behaviors. Progress towards SoC is traditionally
>   achieved through modularity and encapsulation, with the help of
>   information hiding.

From *Pro Asp.Net MVC 4* book ( page 375 ):

> The problem with relying on route names to generate outgoing URLs (
>   @Html.RouteLink("Click me", "MyOtherRoute","Index", "Customer") is
>   that doing so breaks through the separation of concerns that is so
>   central to the MVC design pattern. When generating a link or a URL in
>   a view or action method, we want to focus on the action and controller
>   that the user will be directed to, not the format of the URL that will
>   be used. By bringing knowledge of the different routes into the views
>   or controllers, we are creating dependencies that we would prefer to
>   avoid.

a) I understand that we create a *dependency* ( between *action method/view* and a *routing configuration module* ) by having `Html.RouteLink` ( called within *action method* or *view* ) specifying the name of the *route* we want to use.

But is introducing such a *dependency* already considered a *violation of SoC*? Namely, even though we created a *dependency* between the *two modules*, we haven't actually introduced any additional *functionality/concern* into either of the modules ( the definition of **SoC** implies that *violation of SoC* occurs when *new functionality/concern* is introduced into a *module* )

b) Anyhow, I don't understand how will simply generating an URL ( within *action method/view* ) by specifying a *named route* bring focus to the *format of the URL*?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what the Pro ASP.NET MVC book means is that, by referring to a route by name you have now created a dependency on a particular route definition, rather than relying strictly on the action and controller that will be called.

The route is what determines the shape of the URL.  If you create a link by using a route name, you are literally saying "I want the URL to be this shape," rather than saying "I want the URL to invoke this functionality" and letting the route engine decide which route is most appropriate.

Whether or not this makes sense in your particular application ultimately depends on your needs.  Using a named route creates a level of indirection which allows you to change both the shape of the URL, and the controller/method that gets called, by merely changing the entry in the route table.

As to the coupling aspect, using a named route does tightly-couple the links to that specific route because no other route would be eligible, and because it requires the view to have knowledge of that specific route.  Whether that is a problem or not, again, depends on your needs.  If that coupling is a desirable feature, it doesn't really matter whether it is "tight" or not according to someone else's opinion.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you also comment on my question in a)?

Comment: I apologize for prolonging this topic, but doesn't violating SoC suggest we introduced an additional functionality/concern into a particular module? If so, how does specifying the name of the route ( when calling RouteLink within action method/view ) introduce a new functionality into action method or a view?

Comment: Calling routes by name introduces an additional concern.  Consider what happens if you delete the named route.  If you have links that depend on that route name, you have now broken them, but if your links are based on controllers and methods, deleting the route will not break anything, provided there is another route that can handle the request (perhaps the default route).

Comment: I'm going to mark your post as answer in either case, but if you find the time, here is a follow up question: I'm just having troubles conceptualizing how calling routes by name introduces an additional functionality into an action method/view ( though I understand how calling named routes introduces a dependency ), since to my understanding, dependency != functionality/concern ( I do realize that adhering to SoC majorly reduces dependencies )?

Comment: One way of reducing coupling is by using AOP (you can Google it).  How does it work?  By injecting itself into method calls, or by decorating method calls with some sort of annotation, for logging or other purposes.  We call these "cross-cutting concerns" because they can apply to a wide variety of methods.  Are the methods themselves "concerned" by these injections or annotations?  Not at all.  Are they even aware of the AOP calls?  Nope.  Calling routes by name means that the View now "knows" about the route; it has become a "concern" of the view.

Comment: Ok, one last question - even when adhering to SoC, different modules of functionality still may need to communicate with each other ( via interfaces ). As such, module M knowing about one other modules represents an additional functionality/concern of M? And if M knows about two modules, then we introduced two additional functionalities/concerns into M?

Comment: As you have already figured out, there is no such thing as zero coupling.  Data still has a shape; without that shape, it is just meaningless bits.  In the case of your interface example, one module may know about the interface, and the other module may know about the interface, but *the two modules do not know about each other,* and if the two modules only speak to each other through the interface, you could swap out one module (as long as it implements the same interface), and the other module would never know the difference.

Comment: So in other words, if we make module M aware of an interface ( through which M can communicate with other modules ), then by introducing this interface we haven't necessarily also introduced an additional functionality/concern into M?

Comment: There has to be *some* awareness. No awareness, no communication.  No communication, no program.  It becomes a "concern" when one module must know details about the *inner workings* of another module in order to communicate with it properly.   Interfaces achieve low coupling because they hide the inner workings of one module from the other modules.

Comment: much thanx for all your help

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't violate the SOC principle; the author is wrong.

Named routes typically encapsulate the controller and the action as well as 
URL, which frees the view from having to know them. Used this way they actually 
promote separation of concerns as the view is freed from knowing the name of the 
controller and action.

Here is an example:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "SignUpPromotion", 
                url: "some/url", 
                new { controller = "SignUp", action= "Promotion" });
```

By using `Html.RouteLink("SignUpPromotion")`, I've freed the view from having to know 
the names of the controller and the action. I could rename the action or even move it 
to a new controller without affecting the view or changing the URL.

Comment: I'm not saying this is worth the effort, but I disagree with what the author is saying.

Comment: Also, I've read this book. It's good.